# Extjs 4 dateField getValue

Tags: extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I feel should be easy but still does not work, "toDate.getValue();" does not return Ext.date object. I cannot format date.

Error: format is undefined.

Below is my form field.

```
var toDate = new Ext.form.DateField(
        {
            fieldLabel: "date"
            value: new Date(), name: "abs-to-date",
            width: 100,
            allowBlank: false
        }
```

And on submission of form, i want to format date.

```
var toDateTime = toDate.getValue();
console.log(toDate.getValue());
toDateTime.setHours( toHour.getValue(), toMinute.getValue(), 0 );
abs.to = toDateTime.format( Date.patterns.JSONdateTime );   <---------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 different date type in Extjs 4.

1)    Date

2)    Ext.Date

method "format" is available to Ext.date and toDateTime is object of Date.
following is right syntax.

```
abs.to = Ext.Date.format(toDateTime, Date.patterns.JSONdateTime );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma after 'fieldLabel'.  Code should be:

```
    var toDate = new Ext.form.DateField({
        fieldLabel: "date", //<----------
        value: new Date(),
        name: "abs-to-date",
        width: 100,
        allowBlank: false
    });
```

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake in copy, I have that comma and error raise from "abs.to = toDateTime.format( Date.patterns.JSONdateTime );" this line.