# Error Msg : DateField.getValue() is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, extjs

When I use DateField.getValue(),

```
(this.toDate.getValue()=="" && this.toDate.getValue()=="")
```

I get this error message:

> Error Msg : DateField.getValue() is not a function

following code:

```
function(){
    if(!(this.toDate.getValue()=="" && this.toDate.getValue()==""))
      {
        if(this.frmDate.getValue()>this.toDate.getValue()){
            msgBoxShow(160,1);
            this.frmDate.setValue("");
            return;
        } else {
            //calc duration
         var frm = this.frmDate.getValue().format(Wtf.simplifyDateFormat());
                     var to = this.toDate.getValue().format(Wtf.simplifyDateFormat());
            if((frm!=""&&to!="")){

                                  this.expensesds.load({
                    params:{
                        frmDate:frm,
                        toDate:to,
                        start:0                         

                    },
                    scope: this,
                    callback: function(rec, opt, succ){
                        if(succ){
                            this.expensesds.groupBy("viewby");
                        }
                    }
                });
                this.expensesds.groupBy("viewby");
            }
            else return;
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
},
```

Comment: my Code Is Following:!(this.toDate.getValue()=="" && this.toDate.getValue()=="")

Comment: Can you show the code for `DateField` please? And where do you use `this.toDate.getvalue()` exactly?

Comment: toDate You Have Enter Todate any.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some code. FYI: Extjs is not Java :)

Comment: Please have a look if [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15931863/896249) is helping you

Comment: Please remove 'this' toDate.getValue().Hope it works

Comment: not run sankar bhai..

Comment: can you show us the declaration of toDate?

Comment: this.toDate = new Wtf.form.DateField({
            emptyText:WtfGlobal.getLocaleText("ec.Todate") + "...",
            readOnly:true,
            width : 150,
            value:new Date(),
            format:Wtf.getDateFormat(),
            name : 'todate'
        });

Answer (score 0):

```
this.toDate = new Wtf.form.DateField({
        emptyText:WtfGlobal.getLocaleText("ec.Todate") + "...",
        readOnly:true,
        width : 150,
        value:new Date(),
        format:Wtf.getDateFormat(),
        name : 'todate'
    });
```

**this issue not create if you assign toDate field inside on render or global declaration**

Comment: onRender:function(config) {
        Wtf.tm.reports.ExpenseTypeReport.superclass.onRender.call(this,config);
        this.createReportGrid();
        this.add(this.grid1);
this.toDate = new Wtf.form.DateField({
        emptyText:WtfGlobal.getLocaleText("ec.Todate") + "...",
        readOnly:true,
        width : 150,
        value:new Date(),
        format:Wtf.getDateFormat(),
        name : 'todate'
    });

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can use the ".text()" instead of ".getValue()"...